# iOS Swift SQLite add column to table issue

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I want to add a column to an existing table in sqlite database using swift and this is my code but fails in sqlite3_step.

```
func addFavouriteColumn() -> Bool
{
    var querySql = "ALTER TABLE 'Media' ADD COLUMN Favourite INTEGER DEFAULT 0"
    guard let queryStatement = try? prepareStatement(sql: querySql) else {
        return false
    }
    defer {
        sqlite3_finalize(queryStatement)
    }
    return sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_DONE
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `sqlite3_step()` that's failing and not `prepareStatement()`? What is `sqlite3_step()` returning?

Comment: Yes, prepareStatement is a method and working fine but sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_DONE returns false

Comment: Did you verify that with a debugger or something? How do you tell if it's returning false if `prepareStatement()` failed vs returning false if `sqlite3_step()` doesn't return `SQLITE_DONE`?

Comment: It would help if you actually checked the return value of `sqlite3_step` and look at the result of `sqlite3_errmsg`.

Comment: @Shawn
This is prepareStatement method and it's working fine in debugger and other methods like reading from database

    func prepareStatement(sql: String) throws -> OpaquePointer? {
        var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        guard sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbPointer, sql, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
            throw SQLiteError.Prepare(message: errorMessage)
        }
        return statement
    }

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's working as expected with *other* statements, it matters if it's working with *this* one. But if you've stepped through it with a debugger and verified that that else block that returns false isn't being entered, good (You should include information like that in the question). Now, what is `sqlite3_step()` returning?

Comment: @Shawn
sqlite3_step(queryStatement) returns 8 which represents SQLITE_READONLY !

Comment: Shawn, rmaddy
Thank you all, i moved the database file to documents folder and it's working fine now.

Comment: @NaserMohamed I suggest you either type of a full answer explaining what debugging you did that led to you finding the problem and then what you did to fix the problem, or delete your question.

Comment: @rmaddy
the problem was sqlite3_step(queryStatement) returning 8 which represents SQLITE_READONLY because of database file was in bundle, and i fixed it by moving the database file to the documents folder to be read write and it's working fine for this query and added new column to table.

Comment: @NaserMohamed You need to put that in an answer, not a comment. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site.

Comment: @rmaddy
Done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was sqlite3_step(queryStatement) returning 8 which represents SQLITE_READONLY because of database file was in bundle, and i fixed it by moving the database file to the documents folder to be read write and it's working fine for this query and added new column to table.